# how can i parse a yaml file from a linux shell script

Tags: linux, shell, yaml

I have my YAML file as below:

```
report_id: demographics
columns:
- date
- channel_id
- video_id
- claimed_status
- uploader_type
- live_or_on_demand
report_id: device_os
columns:
- date
- channel_id
- video_id
- asset_id
- claimed_status
- uploader_type
- live_or_on_demand
- subscribed_status
- country_code
- device_type
- operating_system
```

I wanted to parse my YAML file using shell script and wanted the answer as:

```
report_id: demographics
date
channel_id
video_id
claimed_status
uploader_type
live_or_on_demand
report_id: device_os
date
channel_id
video_id
asset_id
claimed_status
uploader_type
live_or_on_demand
subscribed_status
country_code
device_type
operating_system
```

Comment: That is not a valid YAML file, as you have a non-unique key in the top-level mapping (`columns`, `report_id`). You also cannot indent the first `columns` as you did as that will cause a more severe parsing error, but I guess that was typo.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/columns:/d;s/^\s*-\s*//g' file.yml
```

Comment: I wanted to display the content in report_id by parsing yaml file as a function. something like the below code:

Comment: function parse_yaml() {local prefix=$2
   local s='[[:space:]]*' w='[a-zA-Z0-9_]*' fs=$(echo @|tr @ '\034')
   sed -ne "s|^\($s\):|\1|" \
        -e "s|^\($s\)\($w\)$s:$s[\"']\(.*\)[\"']$s\$|\1$fs\2$fs\3|p" \
        -e "s|^\($s\)\($w\)$s:$s\(.*\)$s\$|\1$fs\2$fs\3|p"  $1 |
   awk -F$fs '{
      indent = length($1)/2;
      vname[indent] = $2;for (i in vname) {if (i > indent) {delete vname[i]}}
      if (length($3) > 0) {
       vn="";for (i=0; i<indent; i++){vn=(vn)(vname[i])("_") }
       printf("%s%s%s=\"%s\"\n", "'$prefix'",vn, $2, $3);}}}
parse_yaml $DMF_INIT_CNX_ETC_DIRFILE

Comment: later when i echo report_id, it should display me the two report_id's. I write a case statement next to the code to select the desired report_id content when passed as a variable.

Comment: Unable to read above function `parse_yaml`. Edit the question and include the function in above comments there.